# How to get final overridden chef environment attributes?

Tags: chef-infra

So I have several environments defined on my chef server, with multiple roles that override attributes, and some environment json definitions with overrides as well.  I've been trying to figure out if there's a way to get the details of an environment that takes all the default/override/automatic definitions and shows the final environment that will be used when `chef-client` runs.  Basically a way to verify the final attributes used when chen runs.  `knife environment show <env name>` only shows the environment as defined by the json file, but not the final attributes after all overrides are considered.  Is there a way to run chef-client in `why-run` mode or something and output what it uses in a log or something?  Or is this something that could be gathered via the reporting option?  I don't have direct access to the chef server, and attempts to use `knife runs list` is giving 404 html responses.

I apologize if this is a scrubby question, I'm not particularly familiar with chef.

Answer (score 1):

A coworker helped me out.  I was able to find what I was looking for with the command `knife raw /nodes/<NODE NAME>`, where `<NODE NAME>` is one of the nodes provided by `knife node list`.  This gave me all the attributes visible to the node, including attributes from roles.